# Python not finding modules after installing with pip

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have installed various third party modules with pip and they worked fine until I then ran ccleaner today. Now I cannot import any of these modules.

I've added site-packages to the PATH variable:
C:\Python27\;C:\Users\Rick\PythonScripts;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\

I can import the modules when I run python through command line, but not when I run a script or in a terminal window. They are all running the same version of python: 2.7.12 (in Windows 7).

Any suggestions for how I can fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Check if the packages/modules are still in the *\site-packages\ directory

Comment: *"until I then ran ccleaner"* – well, what did that remove? Have you checked if the packages are still installed?

Comment: Yes, the modules are still in the site-packages folder, and I am able to import them when I run python from the command line.

Comment: What's the difference between "command line" and "terminal window"? How exactly are you executing those scripts?

Comment: They are not being imported into IDLE, through the shell window or the if I execute a script. However, when I run cmd then access python through there they import just fine.

Comment: I should say I'm using windows 7

Comment: With the python installer there is an option to "repair the install" on Windows, see if that fixes it, otherwise I suggest a reinstall of Python.

Comment: OK, I'll give that a go. I don't know whether this is relevant, but I just ran os.getcwd() in both the cmd line python and the idle shell and get different directories.

Comment: What version of python are you running under idle?

Comment: I've tried the repair and that hasn't worked. I have to go now, but I'll try reinstalling it when I get back.

Comment: It's 2.7.12 in all cases

Comment: Try printing sys.path in both env instead of getcwd().

Comment: ok, after running sys.path in idle I get: C:\Windows\system32,   
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\idlelib,    
C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip

Comment: I also get a load relating to ArcGIS

Comment: Whereas when I run it through cmd I get \system32\python27.zip,  then lots of folders within c:\python27\ e.g. DLLs, Lib, Lib\sit-packages, etc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your Path variable needs to modify. This is only used to find binary, not python standard library.

Remove:

```
C:\Python27\;C:\Users\Rick\PythonScripts;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\
```

Add:

```
C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;
```

Edit: do a work-around.

```
import sys
pathLst = [r"C:\Python27\lib\site-packages", r"C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL", r"C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32", r"C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib", r"C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin"]
sys.path.extend(pathLst)
```

Comment: I tried changing the PATH as suggested, but it hasn't affected it. I didn't think it would as the ccleaner hasn't altered the environment variables at all.

Comment: What i have suggested is that your way of setting PATH is wrong, but to fix your problem. In fact, your problem is caused by the sys.path which has no "C:\Python27\Lib\site-package\*", so you can't import these modules. If you want to fix the problem, you can remove your current python which will not remove your 3rd party modules, so when you install it in the same folder again, it will be ok to use them.

Comment: OK, so I've re-installed python 2.7.12. And the problem remains. I get different results from running sys.path depending on how I access python.
As you can see I have arcGIS installed on the computer and it installed it's own version of Python within the Python27\ArcGIS.2.0. I don't whether 
reinstalling that would help, but I'd really rather save that as a last resort because it's difficult and the person at work who can install it 
as currently away. 
How can I set chance the sys.path in IDLE so that it accesses: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages

Comment: sys.path from python via cmd gives:

C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip
C:\Python27\DLLsC:\Python27\lib
C:\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\Python27C:\Python27\lib\site-packages
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin

Comment: but sys.path from IDLE gives:
<ul>
- C:\Windows\system32
- C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\idlelib
- C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip
- C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\DLLs
- C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib
- C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\plat-win
- C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\lib-tk
- C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2
- C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages
- C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\bin
- C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy
- C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\ArcToolbox\Scripts </ul>

Comment: If you want to use 3rd party from idle, you can do a work-around. Appending these path to sys.path "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32 C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin"

Comment: Should I do that via the Environmental Variables -> User Variables in the windows GUI?

Comment: NO.Try the following in the idle."import sys", "sys.path.append(thePathAbove)"

Comment: OK - and should I use the string as you've written it - or do i need to separate paths with semi-colons as its written in the GUI?

Comment: OK, I think I need to add semi-colon separators. How to remove the last path I appended? sys.path[-1].remove()?

Comment: You don't need to add semi-colon.To remove the last path, you can "sys.path = sys.path[:-1]".

Comment: Ok, I've tried it with and without semi-colons and it doesn't work. Also, the changes are erased when I exit and re-open IDLE shell.

Comment: It's just a work-around, it will not affect another session which means you need to enter it in each session!!! In general, i always use command prompt, but idle because there is something bad in idle. And plz post your sys.path here if you have followed me.

Comment: C:\Windows\system32
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\idlelib
C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\ArcToolbox\Scripts
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32 C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin

Comment: I removed some of the arcgis paths as it wouldn't fit.

Comment: OK, I've worked out what the problem was. The shortcut I was using to open IDLE for reasons unclear had changed from my previously installed version of IDLE to the one that ArgGIS installed within the Python27 directory.

Comment: But i am confused. It seems you can import 3rd party modules if your sys.path have changed to that. So i want to know which 3rd party you want to import.

Comment: No, appending to the sys path as you suggested didn't work, so I couldnt import any 3rd party modules. Essentially I installed ArcGIS a few months ago and it installed its own version of python in a folder within the pre-existing c:\python27 folder. This version of python has arcpy installed, but is otherwise standard. I don't understand why, but when I ran ccleaner it somehow changed the shortcut I was using to open IDLE from C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw to C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw - which didn't have any of the modules I wanted installed.